# checking for GNU extensions in Makefiles ... WARNING

Tags: r, devtools

I added the following to my Makevars file:

```
# Set the library flags based on the operating system
ifeq ($(findstring linux,$(OSTYPE)), linux)
    PKG_LIBS = -L$(LIBDIR) -lharmonium -lasound
else
    PKG_LIBS = -L$(LIBDIR) -lharmonium
endif
```

And `devtools::check` is complaining:

```
❯ checking for GNU extensions in Makefiles ... WARNING
  Found the following file(s) containing GNU extensions:
    src/Makevars
  Portable Makefiles do not use GNU extensions such as +=, :=, $(shell),
  $(wildcard), ifeq ... endif, .NOTPARALLEL See section ‘Writing portable
  packages’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.
```

How to avoid this warning while keeping Makevars dependent on `$OSTYPE`?

EDIT: this is the solution I got following Dirk's advice.

```
PKG_LIBS = `os=\`uname -s\`; if [ "$$os" = "Linux" ]; then echo "-L${LIBDIR} -lharmonium -lasound"; else echo ="-L${LIBDIR} -lharmonium"; fi`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `grep` directly and use the shell variable holding the value of the last command to access is.  However, a more common approach is to query `uname -s` and compare. I use both approaches here.

##### Code

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $OSTYPE | grep -q linux
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "We are on Linux (1 of 2)"
    echo "PKG_LIBS = -L${LIBDIR} -lharmonium -lasound"
fi

os=`uname -s`
if [ "$os" = "Linux" ]; then
    echo "We are on Linux (2 of 2)"
    echo "PKG_LIBS = -L${LIBDIR} -lharmonium -lasound"
fi
```

##### Output

While I see `OSTYPE` under bash, it is empty for me in sh making only the second approach viable.

```
$ ./answer.sh 
We are on Linux (2 of 2)
PKG_LIBS = -L -lharmonium -lasound
$
```

In your real use you want to of course assign to `PKG_LIBS` rather than echo it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After struggling a lot I managed to implement your solution with:
`PKG_LIBS = $(shell os=`uname -s`; if [ "$os" = "Linux" ]; then pkg_libs="-L${LIBDIR} -lharmonium -lasound"; else pkg_libs="-L${LIBDIR} -lharmonium -lasound"; fi; echo $$pkg_libs)`. But I still get that warning because of `shell`...

Comment: Yes that is a known GNU Makefile thing too!  I like it better as well, but note how I used backticks.  If you switch to `os=....` using backticks for the command you are good.

Comment: Nice! It's uglier but now it works without warnings. Thanks again! I will put the code on an edited answer.